# HelloWorld error

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

## Introduction

Everyone's first program outputs `Hello World!`. This program should be very simple, that's all you have to do.

## Challenge

Output the string `Hello World!` to the `STDERR`.

## Rules

1. If your language doesn't support `STDERR` or `STDERR` doesn't exist for it, you can output it to it's corresponding error system.
2. You can't output anything else to `STDERR` except for `Hello World!`.
3. You can't output anything to `STDOUT` or take any input from `STDIN`
4. You can't read any content from files.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [PHP has stderr.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Comment: @Mego I personally don't think it's a duplicate. Seeing as how the output method is required to be different, programs cannot just be stolen from that challenge.

Comment: @ETHproductions IMO the different output method (`STDERR` vs `STDOUT`) isn't sufficiently different enough to make it not a dupe. Most of the answers could be trivially transformed by writing to `STDERR` or file stream 1 instead of `STDOUT`.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @Mego. The distinction of writing to STDERR versus STDOUT is pretty trivial in the majority of languages.

Comment: I agree with @Mego and therefore closed this as *duplicate*, not unclear (despite what the banner says). The question is not unclear by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: ***four*** reopen votes!?

Comment: @cat 5, actually. :P

Comment: **Note: The comma in** `Hello, World!` **is not necessary. Please do yourself a favor and save a byte.**

Comment: [Relevant RosettaCode.](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Standard_error)

Comment: @Mego This question's point is about outputting to `STDERR`.  I've seen that Hello World question, and this isn't a copy.

Comment: @ElliotA. Just outputting something to `STDERR` is too trivial. Outputting `Hello, World!` (or any simple variant thereof) is a dupe. Combining those two pieces doesn't make for a good challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Japt, 17 bytes

Currently winning! Let's hope Jelly doesn't pop in with an 11-byte answer...

```
Ox`È*w'HÁM W?ld!'
```

The `?` should be the literal byte 8E. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=T3hgyCp3J0jBTSBXjmxkISc=&input=)

(STDERR is found below the "Upload a file" line in red text.)

#### How it works

```
  `È*w'HÁM W?ld!'  // Decompress this string. Returns "throw'Hello World!'"
Ox                 // Evaluate as JavaScript code. Throws the error.
                   // Implicit: Error is caught by interpreter and sent to STDERR.
```

Alternate version:

```
$throw$`HÁM W?ld!
```

Comment: [Ham World?](http://hamworldinc.com) :P

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ ew ham world. Or should I say "È*w"?

Answer (score 8):

### zsh, <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
<<<Hello\ World!>&2
```

This is a zsh-specific feature; won't work in bash.

Thanks to [@FlagAsSpam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44713/flagasspam) and [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for a byte each!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 30 bytes

```
console.error("Hello, World!")
```

An alternative JavaScript answer, using `console.error`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>75</s> 37 bytes

Thanks to @GamrCorps for slicing the code size almost exactly in half and showing me how to use lambda!

```
()->System.err.print("Hello World!");
```

Using interface because it makes the main declaration shorter. c:

Comment: darn it, you beat me to it!

Comment: @GamrCorps Booyah.

Comment: Hint: Java 8 and use a lambda

Comment: This isn't a full program.

Comment: @feersum I think we by default allow functions unless the question says "full program".

Comment: @ThomasKwa It says "everybody's first program..." Should I make it a program, or no?

Comment: @FlagAsSpam It's not "full program", so no.

Comment: @GamrCorps What's the lambda syntax, again?

Comment: @FlagAsSpam `()->System.err.print("Hello, World!");` should work

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

```
throw"Hello World!"
```

Yes. It's that simple. Try it in the browser console on any page.

Comment: Would using `bota` be shorter (ie `throw bota\`Base64 String Here\``)? idk, i haven't tried it.

Comment: @SpeedyNinja No, the `!` and space will each cause an error if you try to compress it. It wouldn't be worth it anyway.

Comment: Oh ASCII, you're so helpless, ;)

Comment: whyyy doncha adda stack snippet!? :P

Comment: @cat It doesn't really work with a stack snippet, outputting instead `uncaught exception: Hello World!` to an error in the console.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 35 bytes

```c
main(){write(2,"Hello World!",12);}
```

`write` writes to a file descriptor. STDERR is file descriptor 2, and 12 is the length of the string `"Hello World!"`.

Answer (score 3):

### [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), 33 bytes

```
ConsoleWriteError("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>24</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil, then another from @Dennis!

```
echo Hello World!>&2
```

>&2 pushes the output to STDERR.

Comment: Drop the comma, use backslash to quote the `!`, and move the `>&2` to the end without the space, to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Escaping the exclamation point is not required inside a script.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 36 bytes

```
import os
os.write(2,'Hello World!')
```

Despite being based on a Unix syscall, this works as well on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 21 bytes

```
error('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 23 bytes

```r
message("Hello World!")
```

The `message` function writes to STDERR.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 18 bytes

```
warn"Hello World!"
```

This only works if warnings are on (which is the default).

Comment: Works for me with `irb`.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 53 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){std::cerr<<"Hello World!";}
```

You can [try it online](https://ideone.com/dP2SZ6) if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

### Rust, <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
use std::io::Write;fn main(){std::io::stderr().write(b"Hello, World!");}
```

Rust is as long as ever...

Thanks to [@ICanHazHats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45459/i-can-haz-hats) for saving a byte!

Comment: `use std::io::Write;fn main(){std::io::stderr().write(b"Hello, World!");}` is 72 bytes and is working with Rust 1.3 (I don't know how outdated that is)

Comment: @ICanHazHats That does work on the nightly. Thanks!

Comment: Don't thank me, I yanked it straight from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588416/how-to-send-output-to-stderr

Comment: These days you can write `fn main(){eprint!("Hello, World!")}`, but not that it matters as this challenge is closed.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 28 bytes

```
print(STDERR,"Hello World!")
```

Does what it looks like it does. `STDERR` is a built-in constant that refers to the standard error stream and `print` takes an optional argument specifying the stream.

Note that using `error()` prints out a bunch of extra garbage.

Answer (score 2):

## AppleScript, 19 bytes

```
error"Hello World!"
```

...pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Like AppleScript always is.

Comment: @ElliotA. Amen.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 36 bytes

I don't know much PHP, but here goes...

```
<?php fwrite(STDERR,"Hello World!");
```

Tested on ideone.com.

Answer (score 2):

### [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/), 29 bytes

```
stderr.write("Hello World!");
```

This language is probably overkill.

Comment: This language is overkill, unless you have a SuperComputer. Do you have a supercomputer, Phi?

Comment: @cat "The only supercomputer I have is my mind."  (As a serious answer, no, I just put Chapel on my laptop.)

Comment: You shoulda used multithreading for this answer. One thread per character of output, because why not!?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 33 bytes

```
open(2,'w').write('Hello World!')
```

Comment: which py3 version are you running this on? When I try this I get an invalid handle error. (on second thoughts, it's more likely an OS problem)

Comment: @Flp.Tkc It works on both Linux and Windows for me. The stderr = 2 is a feature from Unix, but Python developers ported this special case to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 95 bytes

```
using System;class M{public static void Main(string[]a){Console.Error.Write("Hello World!");}}
```

I'm trying to learn this langauge but god, it's verbose.

Ungolfed:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.Error.Write ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Congrats on exactly 1k rep!

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks! I previously *had* 1.2k but then I gave a bounty for an answer in SPL :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Pike](https://pike.lysator.liu.se), 35 bytes

```cpp
int main(){werror("Hello World!");}
```

Looks like C, isn't C. Is interpreted.

---

We can make this compile as ANSI C like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
# ifndef __PIKE__
#   define werror(x) fputs(x, stderr)
# endif

int main() {
  werror("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: I count 35 bytes...

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I can count today!!

Answer (score 1):

## Pascal (FP/GP), 51 bytes

```
program h;begin writeln(StdErr,'Hello World!');end.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
say stderr"Hello World!"
```

Requires version 5.10 or later.

Thanks to [@FlagAsSpam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44713/flagasspam) for a byte!

Comment: Can you remove the space in `stderr "Hello World!"` (drop the comma).

Comment: Well, I got ninja'd!

Comment: @FlagAsSpam Nope. (This time for real.)

Comment: Hmm. It's really weird - some languages parse `"` as a parenthetical as well, allowing for some interesting stuff (notably in `return""`). I just generally put that down, now, because it's a lot of langs that have that.

Comment: Actually, you can remove the space (tested on perl 5.18.2).

Comment: @FlagAsSpam ...huh. Apparently it didn't work in the debugger for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: This is valid in `5.20.2`, too.

Comment: Why not just `die "Hello World!\n"`? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8lM1VBySM1JydfITy/KCdFkUvp/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 65 bytes

Shorter than factor!

```
outfile-id stderr to outfile-id ." Hello World!" cr to outfile-id
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Moonscript](https://moonscript.org), 40 bytes

```
io.stderr.write io.stderr,"Hello World!"
```

CoffeeScript for Lua... because Lua is ugly as hell!

Answer (score 1):

## Lua5.2, 41 bytes

```
io.stderr.write(io.stderr,"Hello World!")
```

Cheeky golfed version of the  transpilation of [my Moonscript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70085/46231).

Answer (score 0):

## Go, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>37</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
package m;import."os";func main(){Stderr.WriteString("Hello World!")}
```

Comment: This is 37 bytes.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I forgot there was a trailing space, oops! The spec really isn't clear on whether I can give a snippet (this) or a full program -- the C++ one is a full program, this isn't, but it's not said.

Comment: Snippets are never a valid form of answer. Usually programs or functions are, but the question asks for a program.

Comment: @feersum you're right, but it's only mentioned offhandedly, not in the actual spec list.

Comment: Drop the comma.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam thanks for that, I only changed that in the original post and not in the file I copied from :)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
"stderr"~WriteString~"Hello World!"
```

Quite simple.

Comment: This doesn't output an error message.  I think you need to use `Message`.  Anyway, messages appear in red font so as to be easily distinguished from output.

Comment: @DavidC Run this as a script.

Comment: I do not know what a script is.

Comment: @DavidC Just put the code in a file, and run `MathematicaScript -script <file>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Microsoft Windows Batch (also works in Wine), 22 bytes

```
echo Hello World! 1>&2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, <s>19</s> 21 bytes

```
note("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 67 bytes

"Let's use a modernisation of Forth", I said. "It will be fun!" I said.

Yea, the whitespace is needed.

```
error-stream get [ "Hello World!" print flush ] with-output-stream*
```