# Shortest way to get an EOF Error

Tags: code-golf, error-message

It's simple, simply output text to STDERR containing the string `EOF`.

### Input/Output

Your input will be none; however, you should output the message to STDERR.

### Rules

- Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins.
- No standard loopholes please.
- Any method approved by Standard I/O is allowed.
- Your code may not contain the "EOF" that you will output as-is in your error.
- Outputting "EOI" is technically allowed, because the input can also be considered as a separate file.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188973/shortest-way-to-get-a-typeerror) because the TypeError challenge is only defined for one specific language.

Comment: What are compiled languages supposed to do? Do we have to write a program that makes the compiler output "EOF" among other things?

Comment: @someone *output text to STDERR containing the string `EOF` (…), you should also exit the program with a 1 value.*

Comment: Error messages are usually a feature of the compiler, not the language itself. The given example `id(` throws a syntax error when using PyPy instead of CPython. I suggest to include the compiler/interpreter in the answer header, e.g. "Python using CPython".

Comment: [Is this valid?](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/39Xf7f9/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @nimi Invalidated.

Comment: This feels like a more boring version of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70045/helloworld-error with built-in easier to be applied.

Comment: btw there are some answers that have "end of input" instead of "EOF" in the output.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The "HelloWorld error" challenge asks to output a specific string to stderr, this one asks to trigger a specific compiler/interpreter condition. Theses are different tasks, even if some programs may work in both scenarios.

Comment: Seeing as several answers output `end of input` or `end of file` instead of `EOF`, you should clarify explicitly whether this is allowed.

Comment: Is there a requirement for it to be a valid program?
Several answers here assume there is not.

Comment: @A_ wait, what? How can a program be syntactically valid if some part is missing and EOF is thrown?

Comment: voting to close as unclear.  First sentence says to raise an EOF error. Next sentence says to output text to stderr containing EOF. I/O section says you should output a message to STDERR that proves that the program generates an EOFError. All three are asking different things.

Comment: Can we include 'FOE' in our program?

Comment: Yes, because the program outputs 'EOF' but not 'FOE'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) 17.0, 0 bytes

Dyalog 17.0 expects programs to terminate themselves cleanly and will throw an `EOF INTERRUPT` (and exit with a code 2) if they don't: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Xz@/oEQ/N6UyMSc/Xd/QXM9A38xEvzQvMzk/JVUfIvz/PwA)

In contrast, here is the minimal program which does terminate itself cleanly, causing no error (and code 0 upon exit): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/hUd9Ufzc3hRoF/fyCEv3clMrEnPx0fUNzPQN9MxP90rzM5PyUVH2I8P//AA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1 byte

```python
(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X@P/fwA)

A plain opening bracket is interpreted as the start of a tuple. Just having one bracket is enough to raise an EOF error. Also works with `[` and `{`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

```
?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/v9/AA)

When there's no input, an EOF is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/keg/Keg.py", line 500, in <module>
   exec(header + code + footer)
 File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
 File "/opt/keg/KegLib.py", line 119, in Input
   item = input()
 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Also works with `¿`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 1 byte / 7 solutions

The following tokens trigger `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`, or a similar message depending on the JS engine.

```javascript
!
(
+
-
[
{
~
```

Or to summarize:

- unary operators
- opening parenthesis / bracket / brace

#### Exhaustive test on all ASCII characters

```javascript
for(n = 0; n < 127; n++) {
  code = String.fromCharCode(n);
  res = false;

  try {
    eval(code);
  }
  catch(e) {
    res = e.toString() == 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input';
  }
  if(res) {
    console.log(code);
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoJADEX3nKI7hhCJujERWRFPQDzAZOgABlvSGYnGcHYcVBJ3bf/7r1c9amekG/yGuMZ5tiyKoIBtDgQn2O0PYUjTBF4RgAlIyCovHTWZFb6VrZYyXBUleQAEXcit7h3mUdi9PD9FABx1r5b@h5sWmfamVZj8gG8VM89fvUqgKCCunuT14yzCcoQL4WNA47EGpBrYQkfD3cersrMqaFajYXLcY9Zz8/95muc3)

Answer (score 4):

### Turbo Assembler, 0 bytes

Borland Turbo Assembler will print an "Unexpected end of file" when assembling a zero-byte file.

Answer (score 4):

For the python users; the ones posting one character code, technically that is a `SyntaxError` which happens to read as an `EOFERROR`. *(FYI, here's an example of all printable single characters that would cause this same error I'm getting a total of `34`:)*

```
from string import printable

chars = []
for c in printable:
    try: eval(c)
    except Exception as e:
        if 'EOF' in str(e):
            chars += [c]
print(chars)
```

This prints:

```
['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', ']', '^', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~', ' ','\t', '\n', '\r', '\x0b', '\x0c']
```

I'm not sure if `raise EOFError` would be considered an answer as unfortunately that's the shortest code I can think of to raise a legitimate `EOFError` in Python 3:

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 14 bytes

```python
raise EOFError
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vygxszhVwdXfzbWoKL/o/38A)

## OR

**Without implicitly raising the error in Python 2 you could use this at the expense of an extra byte:**

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 15 bytes

```python
input('\u0004')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzOvoLREQz2m1MDAwERd8/9/AA)

Comment: ```raise EOFError``` is considered invalid because the output contains the exact text ```EOFError``` that appears in the source code.

Comment: Why does it not count as an EOF error if it only “happens to read as” one? It does not matter where the EOF comes from, so long as it is an EOF — in the case of single brackets, a source input EOF.

Comment: Because I am avoiding the trivial answer: hard-coding the EOF error output like the program [```EOF```](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39Xf7f9/AA).

Comment: Either way I was simply stating that the one char method doesn’t technically produce a real `EOFError` but in py2 the input method does

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 1 byte

```php
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkDf//BwA)

Run like this: `php -r 1`

Error: `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...`

Any other characters apart from `;`, `#`, space and new line should cause a similar error. So PHP probably has `ASCII characters count - 4` single byte solutions.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell using hugs, 1 byte

```
{
```

The error message contains `unexpected end of input`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NydHNKE0v/v@/@v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Each throws: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

```
´
¥
¶
ª
©
«
§
¨
±
µ
÷
Á
Â
Ò
Ó
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=tA) (Errors are displayed below the output field)

There are also a number of other possibilities, not specific to Japt, that are covered in Arnauld's JS solution, such as:

```
!
&
|
~
^
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 1 byte, 10 solutions

Any of these characters alone will trigger `Error: unexpected end of input`.

```
"
'
`
(
{
+
-
!
?
~
```

Comment: You missed `~` to bring it to an even 10 :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1 byte

Sorry for the edit, misunderstood the question at first :P.
We can do [ or ( or { to get unexpected EOF error. In first case, it expects a list, in second a tuple and so on.

```python
[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P/r/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

**Perl, 1 byte**

`(`

Try it with

```
 perl -e "("
 syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
 Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 1 byte

```java
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/9f9/AA)

---

Old method that's more fun :]

```java
void a()throws Exception{new java.io.DataInputStream(System.in).readInt();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xE4IwDIVn@BUZ28H@AVcdGJwYPYdYehiEtEcD6HH89lo5J6fce8n7Xjqc8eCD4655pjDde7Jge4wRLkgMa1n8zCgoecyeGhjyStUyErfXG@DYRg3yGP0S4fyyLgj5PVqwW3aO0gaVPpbFVqadkNV/YP0ed/kdQ96cULDiMElucTio@h3FDYZYm6ybiiXjtrSlDw)

Comment: I was expecting a one-byte solution... Clever encoding of EOFException though.

Comment: I'll find one for ya.

Comment: @A_ turns out many single characters yield an EOF, haha. At least I've got a runtime version as well :P

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 21 bytes

```
RAISERROR('EOF',11,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 1

```bash
"
```

#### Output

```bash
.code.tio: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
.code.tio: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X@n/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 1 byte

```ruby
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X/H/fwA)

Any of `["!", "(", "*", "+", "-", ":", "[", "{", "~"]` will work depending on the environment.

Comment: You could add `["\"", "%", "'", "/", "\`"]`. It depends on the exact requirement, though. Some will raise SyntaxError mentioning "end of file" or "end-of-input", but I couldn't find any which includes "EOF".

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 1 byte

```ruby
/
```

Outputs `unterminated regexp meets end of file`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X///fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 1 byte

```perl
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/p/38A)

Not very inspired, but it *is* the shortest possible in the language.

Outputs `Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at .code.tio line 1.`

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 0 bytes

All Go files must begin with `package [identifier]`. The error message is:

```
can't load package: package main: 
src/test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```